# Recursive max numbers summing

Tags: c++, knapsack-problem

I am having a problem with recursive solution of the summing problem. The problem is : 
For a given m and n make a program that will sum up n numbers to m so that minimum numbers are used and they are.Id there are multiple solutions, the right one it the one that uses bigger numbers. User inputs n,m and n numbers. For example: m=19 n=4  8,5,4,1 . The solution is 8+5+5+1. if i call the function with the next number in an array and add it while its smaller than sum,  solution will be found only if the next numbers in array can sum up to m. If the problem is like this: m=28 n=3 8,7,5 The solution is 8+8+7+5 but my program would go 8+8+8 and try to add 7 or 5 and would crash because none of them can fit up to 28. So my problem here is going back   more than 2 steps. I can go from 8+8+8+7 to 8+8+8 but can;t go back to 8+8.This is similar to knapsack problem only it is simpler. 
Sorry for not including my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void outputt(vector<int>);

int x(int m,vector<int> s,int n,int u)
{
    static int sum=0;
    static int level=0;
    static vector<int> p;
    sum+=s[u];       
    p.push_back(s[u]);

    if(level==((n-u)+1))
    {
        p.pop_back();
        level=0;
        x(m,s,n,u-1);
    }

    if(sum>m)
    {
        level++;
        sum-=s[u];
        p.pop_back();
        x(m,s,n,u+1);
    }

    if(sum==m)
    {
        outputt(p);
        return sum;
    }
    else
        x(m,s,n,u);

    level++;
    if(level>n-1)
        outputt(p);

    if(sum==m)
        return sum;
    else
    {
        cout<<"....";
        x(m,s,n,level);
    }
}

void outputt(vector<int> x)
{
    for(vector<int>::iterator i=x.begin();i!=x.end();++i)
        cout<<*i<<" ";
}

int main()
{
    int m,n;
    cin>>m>>n;
    int z;
    vector<int> p;
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        cin>>z;
        p.push_back(z);
    }
    cout<<x(m,p,n,0);

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

There is a problem with output but that is not important right now.

Comment: Can we see your code so far please?

Comment: I think your problem statement is not what you meant: "make a program that will sum up n numbers to m so that minimum numbers are used" Did you mean: "draw summands from a set of n numbers with replacement such that they sum up to m and the number of summands is minimal"

Comment: Man, was this homework actually intended for the IOCCC? People are much more likely to help you when they can actually read your code (and question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't far from where you need to be, this will find the solution as quickly as possible (fewest iterations), not the shallowest solution.

```
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename IT, typename IT2>
bool perm_find(int num, IT start, IT last, IT2 output)
{
    for(IT first=start; first!=last; ++first)
    {
        int t=num-*first;
        if(t==0
        ||(t>0 && perm_find(t, start, last, output)))
        {   
            *output++=*first;
            return true;
        }   
    }
    return false;
} 

int main()
{
    int num;
    std::deque<int> pallet, results;

    std::cout << "Enter M: "      << std::endl;
    std::cin  >> num;
    std::cout << "Enter N vals: " << std::endl;

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
              std::istream_iterator<int>(),
              std::back_inserter(pallet));

    std::sort(pallet.rbegin(), pallet.rend());

    perm_find(num, pallet.begin(), pallet.end(), 
              std::back_inserter(results));

    std::copy(results.begin(), results.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
    return 0;
}
```

To modify it so that it gives you shortest possible you will need to go through every valid combination using something like dijstras algo.

EDTT: there was a bug I have fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

- avoid statics in recursive code (you can use it for debugging), let each instance of the function be as independent as possible.
- loop through all your numbers (s) in the function (x) to backtrack to the optimal solution.
- pass the numbers (s) as const reference because they don't change anyway.
- also pass (as value) a container with the already chosen numbers (attempt), so when returning you continue with the previous attempt (backtracking).  This should be your actual state.
- the sum is std::accumulate(attempt.begin(), attempt.end(), 0);
- the level is attempt.size();
- first sort your numbers descending to get the mimimal numbers.
- return the attempt vector if you need it later on (now you are not always returning the sum).